# $.ajax -- put method, sending OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have the following code:

```
function test(segmentId) {
    var url = "http://...../api/avoidsegments/123456";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data : {
            "appID": ig_appID,
            "clientCode": ig_clientCode,
            "segmentID": segmentId
        },
        success: function(output) {
            console.log(output);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('error: ', err);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting the following response:

```
OPTIONS http://...../api/avoidsegments/123456 401 (Unauthorized)

(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://...../api/avoidsegments/123456. 
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

How do I fix this, and send a put request? Thanks.

Comment: it seems like this is about your server-side code, not client side. try to share your related server-side code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do [Cross Origin HTTP Request (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Solution is to [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) on your server side and as i can see u got 401 unauthorized so send Authorization header with requests (i dont know your authorization implementation).

Comment: Note that if using authentication, you'll likely also have to supply an actual origin value rather than `*`.